# PHP usort won't sort class

Tags: php, usort

This is a sample of the array of elemnts to sort:

```
$items = 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'id' => string '110' (length=3)
          public 'brand_id' => string '18' (length=2)
            array
              0 => string ' OT-708' (length=7)
          public 'failed' => null
          public 'diff' => null
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'id' => string '161' (length=3)
          public 'brand_id' => string '18' (length=2)
```

So, let's say I want to sort by `brand_id`.
This is my usort callback function:

```
function _compare($itemA, $itemB){

    if ($itemA->brand_id == $itemB->brand_id) {

        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        return strcmp($itemA->brand_id, $itemB->brand_id); //just an example...
    }

}
```

And when I do `usort($items, '_compare'); var_dump($items);` nothing happens. Any clues on how to troubleshoot this?

**--UPDATE--**

Ok, I've simplified the problem to this:

```
function cmp($itemA, $itemB){
    return -1;
}

if (usort($items, "cmp"))
                echo 'I just sorted!';
else echo 'Cant sort!';
```

It always prints '**Cant sort!**'

Comment: brand_name doesn't even exist in those objects.

Comment: Are you printing the return of `usort` or `$items`? because `usort` only returns a bool on success / false otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I corrected the example.

Comment: I was printing $items. I'll check the compare function return.

Comment: I've updated the question, usort always fails for me.

Comment: @ign it's `if (usort($items, "cmp"))`, NOT `if (usort(items, "cmp"))`, rihgt?

Comment: Yes, $items, sorry, I already feel like an idiot.

Comment: @ign you could do `var_dump($items);` before `usort`? Does it show anything? Or could you show us more of your code?

Comment: OK, I figured it out... My mistake for thinking I had error reporting ON. All this code, including function cmp is inside a class, so I was getting this and didn't realize "( ! ) Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'cmp' not found or invalid function name in ..."

Comment: @ign , nice you could now insert your problem solution as an answer and accept it for future readers that could have a similar problem.

Comment: Yeah, I will as soon as SO lets me. Thanks for your help, it would have taken me a while more without it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Finally, I discovered the source of this error. The problem was that this code was inside a class.

If that's your case, then you should call usort this way:

```
usort($items, array("MyClass", "compare_method"));
```

Furthermore, if your Class is in a namespace, you should list the full namespace in usort.

```
usort($items, array('Full\Namespace\WebPageInformation', 'compare_method'));
```

Comment: Thanks, got the same problem with uksort. The documentation says uksort will return true or false, and it was returning null.

Comment: If anyone else is still having issues, try making your compare function `static`.

Comment: You can also replace the class name with `$this` as the first element in the array. This is equiv to `$this->compare_method($a, $b)` so make sure the function is set to `public`. Otherwise `usort` is trying to do `MyClass::comapre_method($a, $b)` so make sure the function is set to static.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can set a static function inside your Class:

```
static myfunction($a, $b){'yoursort'}
```

and call it like this:

```
usort($items, "Class::myfunction");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$this` if you use `usort` in a `Class`:

```
usort($my_array, array($this, 'orderByDate'));
```