# weirdest function with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, usort

alright, I'm trying something which should be like really easy.

Here it is:

```
usort($newarr, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b)
{ return 0; }
```

The problem is simple: it does not sort the array by giving this warning message

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'cmp' not found or invalid function name
```

---

I have read this answer here [PHP usort  won't sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419818/php-usort-wont-sort)

but it just doesn't make any sense to me, I do not have a class like how it is explained in the answer 1 (and I don't even need any, i tried with $this, this, insted of "myclass" but it's simply not working any):

```
usort($items, array("MyClass", "compare_method"));
```

Comment: I can't recall if that might be the problem, but try to include function above usort instead of below.

Comment: Is the call to `usort()` in the same scope as `cmp`? If it is, is `cmp` defined inside a class?

Comment: try to place your sort function definition BEFORE calling `usort()` in code.

Comment: @enrico: Your code should be working ok. Which PHP version are you using and what you posted is *exactly* the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script flow, by the time you are trying to sort your array `cmp` does not exists yet. So, this should work:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{ return 0; }

usort($newarr, "cmp");
```

Comment: Actually the other way round works as well, so why change it?

Comment: Really? How it's so? PHP have a crystall ball to determine the existence of function defined later? :)

Comment: I can't believe this, i changed the order and it doesn't give me an error anymore O_o

Comment: @J0HN - no crystal ball necessary. PHP parses the file *then* executes it. It is not parsed and executed line by line.

Comment: @PaulDixon, maybe I'm writing this from parrallel universe, or maybe I'm not getting something, or maybe I'm mistaking, but PHP always complained about undefined functions. Could you plese point me out on some documentation page that says I'm wrong?

Comment: althought strangely it works in the way john explained! I was getting crazy before!

Comment: @enrico: what versions of PHP are you using?

Comment: in older php versions you can use a function before its definition, when you are in global scope and outside any control-structure. because in past functions were compiled before the actual execution of the procedure... i'm pretty sure that this is true! who confirms?

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've posted with your question, it can not be specifically said why it does not work for you.

The code generally does work, it's perfectly alright ([Demo](http://codepad.org/2Udi2FBm)):

```
<?php
$newarr = array();

if (!function_exists('cmp')) echo "cmp() not defined yet.\n";
usort($newarr, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b)
{ return 0; }
```

I suggest you add more information to your question so it can be better said where the actual problem is located.

- Which PHP version are you using?
- Do you make use of namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) (or `create_function`) to create an anonymous function like your `cmp`, then pass it to `usort`.

Example:

```
usort($newarr, function($a, $b) {
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Better use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) than `create_function`.

Comment: @hakre It depends on the PHP version. If on a shared host, it'll probably not have PHP 5.3, but that's an option as well.